# get error from proguard

Tags: android, proguard

When I try to export an `.apk` file it gives me this error:

```
[2013-06-10 13:46:47 -] Proguard returned with error code 1. See console
[2013-06-10 13:46:47 -] Warning: com.facebook.widget.FacebookFragment: can't find referenced method 'android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity getActivity()' in class com.facebook.widget.FacebookFragment
```

What could be the reason for it? I dont understand what `dontskipnonpubliclibraryclassmembers` means?

Thanks

Comment: add this to your prougard.cfg file and see the results :
-ignorewarnings
i think this warning is not that risky

Comment: I edited my question, can you please look again?

Comment: make sure that the project.properties file contains the right config file path and add these 
-dontwarn org.mockito.**
-dontwarn sun.reflect.**
-dontwarn android.test.**
-dontwarn com.facebook.widget.FacebookFragment.**

Comment: I have 79 warnings like this... should I ignore them all?!

Comment: in this case please take a look at this :
http://proguard.sourceforge.net/index.html#manual/troubleshooting.html
how does proguard work , You have to reassure ProGuard that some suspicious constructs in the input jars are ok, that's why we ignore warnings this way , but in your case please take a look proguard Troubleshooting link i sent you above :)